# Json deserialize returning null

Tags: c#, json

Here is the JSON response

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "sys_id": "85071a1347c12200e0ef563dbb9a71c1",
      "number": "INC0020001",
      "description": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my JSON class

```
    public class Result
{
    public string sys_id { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class jsonResult
{
    public IList<Result> result { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what I am doing to deserialize

```
strReponse = rClient.makeReqest();
Result deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(strReponse);
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(deserializedProduct.number);
```

It looks like it never assigns anything into my JSON class.
This is my first time dealing with JSON and Web calls. What am i missing? The API call does return the correct JSON, and I used json2csharp to make my json class.

Thank you!

Comment: Should be `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonResult>(strReponse)`

Comment: You need to deserialize into the class `jsonResult` (consider renaming that/putting it in proper casing).  You are deserializing into `Result` which is why your code is failing.  Do what @Fabio said and you will be fine.

Comment: I get "cannot implicitly convert type servicenowaddin.jsonresult to servicenowaddin.result
Result deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonResult>(strReponse);

Comment: @ffalor well of course you will, you never changed the type of your variable:  `jsonResult deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonResult>(strReponse);`

Comment: You have to change the variable declaration also....

Comment: Yeah i used to do the jsonResult, but everytime i did the deserializedProduct would never let me access any of the properties. Like deserializedProduct.number. However Fabio's answer worked the one he posted. Why do i have to split it up like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need deserialize full object represented in json string. Which is `jsonResult` in your case.

After, you will get access to values, you need, through properties of `jsonResult`

```
strReponse = rClient.makeReqest();
var deserializedResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonResult>(strReponse);
var number = deserializedResult.result.First().number;
MessageBox.Show(number);
```

Because `jsonResult.result` is of type `IList` will be safer to loop through all possible results

```
strReponse = rClient.makeReqest();

var deserializedResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonResult>(strReponse);
foreach (var result in deserializedResult.result)
{
    MessageBox.Show(result.number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should deserialize to `jsonResult` **NOT** `Result`.

So try this :

```
jsonResult deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonResult>(strReponse);
```

Also you may get values of the list like this:

```
var firstResult = deserializedProduct.result.FirstOrDefault();
var someSpecialResults = deserializedProduct.result.Where(r=>r.number.Contains("123"));
```

Also :

```
if (firstResult != null)
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(firstResult .number);
```

Also you may iterate them like this :

```
deserializedProduct.result.ForEach(r=> System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(r.number);)
```

I hope to be helpful for you:)